# delegate for all methods

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to implement a `TaskQueue`. 
I add Tasks to a Queue and when I call `Run()` the Tasks will be executed by a thread.

```
class Executer
{
    private Queue<Task> TaskQueue;

    private Thread thread;

    public Executer()
    {
        this.TaskQueue = new Queue<QueueNode>();
    }

    public void AddTask(Task task)
    {
        this.TaskQueue.Enqueue(task);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        this.thread = new Thread(() => ThreadMethod);

        this.thread.Start();
    }
}
```

`ThreadMethod` loops through the `Queue` and executes the `Task`s.

But my problem is that I can not find a datatype for `Task`, because `Task` could be everything.

Assume I only want to call Methods with an `int` parameter. Then it is very easy.. `Task` could be this:

```
Action<int> Task = object.AddToTheObjectCounter(5);
```

But that's only one case from infinitely many.

Can you give me a tip?

I also have thought about calling the methods dynamically by

```
object.GetType().GetMethod("AddToTheObjectCounter") // ...
```

but I think that this is not good, because when I have a spelling mistake the code compiles but will crash.

---

**HINT:**
I figured out that you can Invoke the Delegate (look answer below) with a variable count of parameters:

```
private void TestMethod()
{
    Delegate function = (Func<int, int, int>)((a, b) => a * b);
    object[] parameters = new object[] {7, 2};
    var result = (int)function.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is the [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
private Queue<Delegate> TaskQueue;
...

public void AddTask(Delegate task)
{
    this.TaskQueue.Enqueue(task);
}
```

However, when adding a task using `AddTask`, it won't be that easy as before. You'll first need to convert into a known delegate (`Func<>`), and then pass an argument.

```
obj.AddTask((Func<...>)nameOfTheMethod);
// obj.AddTask((Func<string[], void>)Console.WriteLine);
```

When you call the `Delegate` instance, you can't use `operator()` because you are uncertain of what the function actually is. You have to use [`DynamicInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Nice idea. But i have one problem. Your code is working, but i can't call the task. When i am in my thread and i want to call the function with values i can't do it, because i can't use the Delegate task as a method (error). I think i have to cast it first back into the Func<...> - any ideas?

Comment: This is the full error: Non-invocable member 'ThreadQueue.QueueNode.Function' cannot be used like a method. - Function is task in this case

Comment: @JensHorstmann Because of you don't know what the return type or the paramaters are when talking about a `Delegate` instance, `DynamicInvoke` method must be used instead.

Comment: Very nice anwer. `DynamicInvoke` is the perfekt tip. Thx for you help!

Comment: @JensHorstmann Thank you too, an interesting question :) +1 Please note that `DynamicInvoke` may not be the fastest way of doing things, as it's heavily runtime-dependent.

Comment: yes i know. but thats no problem. i am also using a Dispatcher in the thread ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous methods:

```
void Print(string str) {
    Console.WriteLine("str");
}

var queue = new List<Action> {
    () => Print("Hello"),
    () => Print(" world!"),
    () => {
        Print("Bla bla bla");
        Print("-----------");
    }
};
for each(var task in queue) {
    task();
}
```

Result will be:

```
Hello
 world!
Bla bla bla
-----------
```